# how to center columns group

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="linksbwrap">
<a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a><br>
<a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem</a><br>
<a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a><br>
<a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem</a><br>
...
</div>
```

css

```
#linksbwrap{
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
```

How to set left margin of the first column to be the same as the right margin of the last column ?

And keep the links inside columns aligned left.

I tried:

```
 #linksbwrap{
        text-align:center;
    }
```

but in this case links inside columns are also centered by itself.

Comment: provide css of .linkb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't this work?

```css
#linksbwrap {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  background:lightblue;
  margin: 0 40px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="linksbwrap">
  <a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a><br>
  <a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem</a><br>
  <a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a><br>
  <a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem</a><br>
  <a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a><br>
  <a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem</a><br>
  <a class="linkb" href="">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: You can see that left/right margins are not the same

Comment: @bonaca Are we talking about the right space in each column should be matched on the first columns left side, so in my answer it should be more blue space to the left of the first column?

Comment: @bonaca Updated my answer. Is this how you want?

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix the width and keep it in the center place. So that it will give you the result like left and right margin are same.

```
#linksbwrap{
 -webkit-column-count: 4;
 -moz-column-count: 4;
 column-count: 4;
 margin:0px auto;
 width:80%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nt4wzqzg/2/)

Comment: You can see that left/right margins are not the same

Comment: what is not same? are you verifying the margin with the text ending. If yes,  it is wrong. You should verify with the box sizing not text size.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `online css generators` like:

[CSS3Generator.com](http://css3generator.com/)

you can try different properties and find the best one for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your CSS

```
#linksbwrap {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
```

This will leave equal space on the left of the 1st element and the right of the last element

Comment: In this case all columns and links are messed !